# 'style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px"' to js object by python re.sub

Tags: javascript, python, regex, reactjs, jsx

I'm frontend developer and working with `IUEditor`, which can make `html/css/js` from design.

But sadly, our project is made of React, so i have to compile html to jsx. so I made it by myself, using python, except one left.

I have to change

> style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px"

attribute to jsx object, that supposed to be

> style={{border: none, overflow: hidden, height:80px}}

You may ask, why not use https://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html, but actually IUEditor use it's one attributes on other places, and jsx doesn't allow to use them by default.

Anyway, problem is I want to change style html tag to style object of jsx by python re.sub method. How can I do this?! Ask for helps from regex masters ;)

Comment: Why does it need to be an object? The style should be able to apply itself as a string and still style the element. Do you need to access the style as a prop in the child component?

Comment: If you are looking for a regex solution, you should probably add the [`regex`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag.

Comment: @Rahat Ahmed https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html tells that style tag must be an object...am I correct?

Comment: @Jason Estibeiro thx. I'll.

Comment: Ah, seems like you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's simpler with `re.search` method. You get the results and construct the JSX. I am not perfect at Phyton but in JS this could easily be accomplished by

```
var str = 'style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px"',
    rex = /\s*[\w-]+\s*:\s*[\w-]+\s*/g,
    res = str.match(rex),
    jsx = "style={{" + res[0] + "," + res[1] + "," + res[2] + "}}";
```

The regex should be the same. In JS you get an array of matches and in Phyton you should be returned an object in a similar fashion. Then it's all about re-composing the string. Try it on console.

Ok according to the comment. Here is a reusable version of this snippet. It should work for as many CSS properties you may have in your inline style.

```
var str = 'style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px"',
    rex = /\s*[\w-]+\s*:\s*[\w-]+\s*/g,
    res = str.match(rex),
    len = res.length,
    jsx = "style={{";

for (var i = 0; i< len-1; i++){
  jsx = jsx + res[i] + ",";
};
jsx = jsx + res[len-1] + "}}";
```

Comment: Thx for ur help. Actually it have to be more universal(?) - for example there can be more than 3 or less than 3 of style elements. Anyway thank u, i will try with your surgestion ;)

Comment: I've got your point. It's also ver simple. Actually i was going to write a reusable version but i guess i have been a little lazy. I will correct my code accordingly.